# Sybase lead blocker in chain

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

What would be a query to list a blocking chain in Sybase ASE 16?  In SQL server I'd use something like this: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/07/sql-server-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you getting your blocker/blockee info from? what format are looking for as output?

Comment: https://www.petersap.nl/SybaseWiki/index.php?title=Sp_block--check_analyse_blocked_processes

Comment: Sybase ASE does not have any SQL constructs (eg, CTE, builtin recursive-like functions) that would allow you to use a single query; you **can** **a)** write a stored proc to do what you want or **b)** create a user-defined function (UDF) that can recursively do what you want ... and you can access both of these methods via a single query (eg, via a proxy-table built on top of the stored proc; via a UDF reference in your query); net result is you **can** build something in ASE to do what you want ... it just comes down to questions of output format and how to access the code (query vs proc)

Comment: actually, a UDF wouldn't need to be recursive as it could also be coded with a looping construct